# Force SSL on Express server with SPDY

Tags: express, https, http2

I'm trying to force HTTPS for the whole app that uses Express 4.16.3 and `spdy` for HTTP/2 support. Navigating via the `https` URL scheme works, but apparently no redirecting take place for `http`, since no debug messages are logged.

```
const app = express();
const spdy = require('spdy');
app.use(function enforce_ssl(req, res, next)
{
    console.log(`${req.method} ${req.protocol}://${req.headers.host}${req.originalUrl}`);
    if(req.secure)
        next();
    else
        res.redirect(301, `https://${req.headers.host}${req.originalUrl}`);
});
<...>
const server = spdy.createServer(
{
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(cwd, 'stub-cert.pem')),
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(cwd, 'stub-privkey.pem')),
}, app);
server.listen(port, (err) =>
{
    if(err)
    {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    else
        console.log(`Listening on port ${port}!`);
});
server.on('error', (err) => console.error(err));
```

I get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` page when navigating via "insecure" protocol. How to fix this?

Comment: Are you exposing nodejs directly on port 80 and 443 to the rest of the world / the rest of your network? If so, I'd consider making your nodejs code only use HTTP, make it listen on something like port 8083 and then use something like NGinx as a reverse proxy. Using node for https is fine, but generally nginx is much more secure and also brings in a bunch of caching settings for you. It's generally a bad idea to expose a node process directly to "the world". You can then do HTTPs and force a HTTP -> HTTPS redirect in nginx.

Comment: There's no need to be rude. It being tangential is why I left this as a comment and not an answer. StackOverflow questions are also useful for future readers, providing the additional information might be useful to those folks who may not be aware of the more traditional route.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be rude. You must understand that receiving irrelevant answers can be frustrating, maybe that's why my response seemed to be rude.

Comment: StackOverflow enforces a code of conduct which is worth reviewing https://stackoverflow.com/conduct in preparation for future Q&A.